# JQGRID - I'm using Add new record and editing forms

Tags: jqgrid

In both of those forms (edit and new), i setted different bSubmit caption,
and different reloadAfterSubmit event.

The problem,
those settings overrided each by the other,
depends on who the first of the events to be fired.

How can I create two differences buttons of bSumbit and the other properties?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of [recreateForm:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) property for both Add and Edit forms should solve the problem. Sime time before I suggested to make this setting as default (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/change-default-settings-for-recreatefilter-and-recreateform-to-true/#p21082)), but default value of the `recreateForm` property still `false`.